# spark job runs in client mode but not run in cluster mode due to permission issue

Tags: linux, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, hadoop2

I am running my spark-job using spark-sbumit script file as below

```
export SPARK_HOME=/local/apps/analytics/spark-2.4.1-bin-hadoop2.7
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode client\
```

When I run it in cluster mode i.e

```
--deploy-mode client\
```

It is giving an error as below:

```
INFO yarn.Client:
         client token: N/A
         diagnostics: User class threw exception: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=analytics, access=WRITE, inode="/tmp/hadoop-egsadmin/nm-local-dir/usercache"
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:350)
```

> How to fix this issue? what is wrong here?